# Regex pattern matching last word in parentheses containing all parentheses

Tags: arrays, regex, if-statement, google-sheets, re2

I need help matching these patterns all at once. I am using Google Sheets REGEXEXTRACT.

This is what I have so far:

```
\(.+\)
```

This matches (Jake), (The LGS Regiment) (Bob), and (John (Wake)) from the examples below. I need to find a way to not include parentheses and match just what is inside the last parenthetical closure. Any regex wizards out there have any ideas?

> The Liberated Guardsmen of Solemnace (The LGS Regiment) (Bob)
> The Tribulation of St. Genevael (John (Wake))
> Hive Fleet Oblivion (Jake)

I need to match:

> Bob
> John (Wake)
> Jake

Comment: What have you tried? Which regular expression engine are you using? What errors or mismatches are you getting? Why isn't your code giving you the results you expect?

Comment: I have updated my question, I hope that is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(
 REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A3, "\((.+\))"), "(.+)\)"), "\((.+[a-z]$)"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A3, "\((.+\))"), "(.+)\)")))
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect! I am going to break this down and figure out how this works for next time. Thanks!